# Heroku error logs without heroku command

Tags: heroku

How can I check the error logs of Heroku,
without running:

```
heroku logs
```

Since I'm using Codeship.io, I can't use 'heroku' commands

Answer (score 0):

There is a free heroku add on, Papertrail.

And this to your heroku app (can be done command line or via the heroku UI)
then on your Resources tab you can click Papertrail.

Helpfull note with Papertaril, you can set up email notifications on string comparisons. This can help for early fault detection.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the heroku app you could view the logs from there:
(open the app page then press the dotted more button on the top right then press view logs)

(requires you to keep the logs page open)

[logs one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aXCYO.png)

[logs two](https://i.stack.imgur.com/944h0.png)

---

or set up a webhook
(open the app page then press the dotted more button on the top right then press view webhooks and once the page has loaded click create webhook then set-up your webhook)

(i use it with discord: Ohttps://support.discordapp.com/hc/en-us/articles/228383668-Intro-to-Webhooks)

(may not have an error option)

[webhooks one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QbiEb.png)

[webhooks two](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ajnvC.png)

[webhooks three](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Vu97.png)

---

or like gregmcpugh said you could use the add on papertrail. (which i also use)

> There is a free heroku add on, Papertrail.
>
> And this to your heroku app (can be done command line or via the heroku UI) then on your Resources tab you can click Papertrail.
>
> Helpful note with Papertrail, you can set up email notifications on string comparisons. This can help for early fault detection.

(no bad thing i can say about this one!)

[papertrail one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lsQQ5.png)

[papertrail two](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rlD5y.png)

[papertrail three](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WiScC.png)

*damn people being before me :P*

**hope i helped! :D**

Comment: Adding screenshots might be more useful than descriptions of the UI.